# Crawl a news website and getting the news content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parser

I'm trying to download the text from a news website. The HTML is:

```
<div class="pane-content">
<div class="field field-type-text field-field-noticia-bajada">
<div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item odd">
                 <p>"My Text" target="_blank">www.injuv.cl</a></strong></p>         </div>
```

The output should be: My Text
I'm using the following python code:

```
try: 
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "My URL"
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
p = parsed_html.find("div", attrs={'class':'pane-content'})
print(p)
```

But the output of the code is: "None". Do you know what is wrong with my code??

Comment: Even when you would parse the HTML and not the URL, the HTML isn't valid. You can't parse that with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @tobltobs `BeautifulSoup` attempts to fix broken HTML; It can parse that HTML just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that **you are not parsing the HTML, you are parsing the URL string**:

```
html = "My URL"
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Instead, you need to *get/retrieve/download the source first*, example in Python 2:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

html = urlopen("My URL")
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

In Python 3, it would be:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("My URL")
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Or, you can use the third-party "for humans"-style [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests

html = requests.get("My URL").content
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

---

Also note that you should not be using `BeautifulSoup` version 3 at all - it is not maintained anymore. Replace:

```
try: 
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

with just:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

`BeautifulSoup` accepts a string of HTML. You need to retrieve the HTML from the page using the URL.

Check out [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) for making HTTP requests. (Or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for an even simpler way.) Retrieve the HTML and pass *that* to `BeautifulSoup` like so:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get the HTML
conn = urllib.urlopen("http://www.example.com")
html = conn.read()

# Give BeautifulSoup the HTML:
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

From here, just parse as you attempted previously.

```
p = soup.find("div", attrs={'class':'pane-content'})
print(p)
```